# How do you add a button inside of a for loop?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a program that asks the user for a number through an Alert Dialog(That part is complete) but then I would like to generate as many buttons as the user specified. I tried to make a for loop to create the buttons, but I can't get it to work properly:

```
    Button[]buttons;
    buttons = new Button[numOfButtons];
    for(int i = 1;i!=numOfButtons;i++){
        buttons[i-1] = new Button(this);
        layout1.addView(buttons[i-1]);

    }
```

The only logical way that I thought I could get this to work was to use an array since I don't believe you can keep declaring new variables inside a loop, but this doesn't seem to work. Sorry if this is bit silly, I'm still new to all this. It gives a fatal exception error.

Full Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Editable numButtons;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    RelativeLayout layout1 = new RelativeLayout(this);
    setContentView(layout1);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Enter the number of buttons: ");

    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    builder.setView(input);

    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            numButtons = input.getText();
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    builder.show();

    Button[]buttons;
    int numOfButtons = Integer.parseInt(numButtons.toString());
    buttons = new Button[numOfButtons];

    for(int i = 1; i != numOfButtons; i++){
        buttons[i-1] = new Button(this);
        layout1.addView(buttons[i-1]);

    }
}
}
```

Comment: your for loop is wrong. it should be `for(int i=0;i<numOfButtons;i++)`

Comment: `but I can't get it to work properly` Explain the problem. Is it compile time or run time?

Comment: You can declare variables inside a loop, but an array works too.  Your loop is a little odd, usually you would loop for(i<0; i< numOfButtons; i++).  Define not work though-  that will help us help you

Comment: what's the type of layout1? what does not work?

Comment: Hi everyone, very sorry for being vague! It gives a fatal exception.

Comment: @Aamir That's still vague.

Comment: @Aamir The exception message is what we require to help you. Also, you can declare variables just fine inside a loop because it is a scope, you just can't reuse variable names from parent scopes

Comment: Have you tried creating **one** button in Java code and adding it to your view hierarchy?

Comment: "it gives a fatal exception" then that's where you should be looking. read the error, try to understand it. It usually contains all sort of interesting information.

Comment: There could be any number of reasons why it doesn't work.  We don't know what layout1 is.  That could be a problem.  We don't know if layout1 is configured to show the buttons as you expect.  We also don't know exactly what all these buttons should look like on screen.  Please provide more code for context.

Comment: Ok I added the rest of the code. It might actually be a problem with numOfButtons since I was trying to make it an int? Here's the error message:

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference

Comment: I suggest creating **one** button and adding it programmatically. When you get this to work then you can move on to adding multiple buttons.

Comment: Hi Code-Apprentice. I just tried it and was able to put one button onto the interface. So that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Post the full stack trace of the error (with the line numbers noted in your code) in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AlertDialog button click is *asynchronous* so as soon as the code hits this line...

```
int numOfButtons = Integer.parseInt(numButtons.toString());
```

you will get a `NullPointerException` because `numButtons` is null at that point.

Please try this instead. Assuming the `layout1.addView` works as it should. Note, you'll need to make `layout1` final or move it out as a class field to reference the variable here.

```
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        numButtons = input.getText();

        int numOfButtons = Integer.parseInt(numButtons.toString());
        Button[] buttons = new Button[numOfButtons];

        for(int i = 0; i < numOfButtons; i++){
            buttons[i] = new Button(MainActivity.this);
            layout1.addView(buttons[i]);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This makes sense but the code is still giving me issues. I made layout1 final and added in this code into the right place, but it's giving me a problem specifically with this line: buttons[i] = new Button(this); The (this) is giving me a syntax error

Comment: Specifically this error is coming up: Button(android.content.Context) in Button cannot be applied to (anonymous android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener)

Comment: Whoops, yes. See edit